# Can't change Windows Firewall startup type, it always set to "Manual"

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, windows-firewall

I struggle with this simple task, to change startup type of Windows Firewall service to "Automatic" but always fails, after rebooting it restoring to ["Manual."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzyMi.png)

It affects me, and my users, because Windows Firewall service required for another features and applications, for example Windows Search, after updating OS i detected that all Windows 10 apps and Windows Search stop working.I tried to implement bug-fix with Powershell cmdlet to re-register apps and everything seems to be fine and apps with search worked, but after rebooting search stopped.

This issue implementing on different OS:

- Windows 7
- Windows 8.1
- Windows 10
- WS2012R2

**!But not on WS2008R2!**

All computers in a domain, and GP is clear, i couldn't find anything that can affect Windows Firewall. Here is GPresult [report](https://yadi.sk/d/0KTvupWi3HALx8)

Comment: In your default domain policy, the service is set to start automatically.
This is the winning GPO, and thus it does set it to start automatically.
The only thing I can think of is that something else is setting it to Manual instead, afterwards. Perhaps a script, piece of software or scheduled task running either locally (maybe a part of installation images?) or centrally (script run by a gpo perhaps? - it's unclear what the "Change_Desc_AD_on_PC.exe" acutally do, which is run by "Users&PC's" GPO).
Further, do you have logonscripts through AD accounts?

Comment: @MikaelDyreborgHansen Thank you for the reply. I have already find an answer, you are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason of this fault is GP. The MpsSvc service was set to "Stop" and"Manual" in User&PC's policy.